# Weird Characters when Writing to File (Mac) (Java)

Tags: java, file-io, osx-snow-leopard

I'm working on Mac (Snow Leopard). Using Java, I clear file contents and then write to it. 
That's the code to clear the file:

```
   new File(FileName).delete();
   new File(FileName).createNewFile();
```

Afterwards, when I write to the file, I find weird characters; for example:
instead of writing:

> expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’

it writes:

> expected ‚Äò=‚Äô, ‚Äò,‚Äô, ‚Äò;‚Äô, ‚Äòasm‚Äô

I'm sure that createNewFile() causes the problem, because no problem occurs when I write the same text to a file I created manually. What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you using to write to the file? Are you using an OutputStreamWriter wrapped in a BufferedWriter, and specifying the OutputStreamWriter's Charset?

Comment: You don't need to delete the file and re-create it to replace its content. Just write to the file. I also suspect an encoding problem.

Comment: Actually it is written by the gcc command through terminal using this command: $(foreach f, $(CFILES) , gcc $f 2>> errors.txt;)

Comment: I am writing the errors of gcc compilation to a text file

Comment: As @JBNizet mentioned I don't need to delete and re-create the file. So I just write empty string to the file to clear it. 

    `BufferedWriter Writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(ErrorFileName));
    Writer.write("");
    Writer.close();`

Answer (score 2):

You're introducing a transcoding error somewhere.

You are encoding the data as UTF-8 in Java but whatever you're using to decode it is treating the data as (probably) MacRoman.

Or, your Java editor is saving the file as UTF-8 and your compiler is decoding it as MacRoman prior to compilation.

Read [this](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html).